# What do the 4 numbers mean in Mapbox's heatmap specification?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Mapbox has an [example heatmap page](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/heatmap-layer/). Several times, 4 numbers (`0,0,6,1`, `0,1,9,3`, `0,2,9,20`, and `7,1,9,0`) appear in the specification:

```
// Increase the heatmap weight based on frequency and property magnitude
'heatmap-weight': [
'interpolate',
['linear'],
['get', 'mag'],
0,
0,
6,
1
],
```

or:

```
// Increase the heatmap color weight weight by zoom level
// heatmap-intensity is a multiplier on top of heatmap-weight
'heatmap-intensity': [
'interpolate',
['linear'],
['zoom'],
0,
1,
9,
3
],
```

or:

```
// Adjust the heatmap radius by zoom level
'heatmap-radius': [
'interpolate',
['linear'],
['zoom'],
0,
2,
9,
20
],
// Transition from heatmap to circle layer by zoom level
'heatmap-opacity': [
'interpolate',
['linear'],
['zoom'],
7,
1,
9,
0
]
```

[This page](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/make-a-heatmap-with-mapbox-gl-js/) explains the concept of *heatmap-weight*, *heatmap-intensity*, *heatmap-radius* and *heatmap-opacity*, the concepts the above code deals with:

> **heatmap-weight:** Measures how much each individual point contributes to
> the appearance of your heatmap. Heatmap layers have a weight of one by
> default, which means that all points are weighted equally. Increasing
> the heatmap-weight property to five has the same effect as placing
> five points in the same location. You can use a stop function to set
> the weight of your points based on a specified property.
>
> **heatmap-intensity:** A multiplier on top of heatmap-weight that is
> primarily used as a convenient way to adjust the appearance of the
> heatmap based on zoom level.
>
> **heatmap-radius:** Sets the radius for each point in pixels. The bigger
> the radius, the smoother the heatmap and the less amount of detail.
>
> **heatmap-opacity:** Controls the global opacity of the heatmap layer.

However, I am not clear with what each of the repeatedly appearing 4 numbers represent.

**How do each of the 4 numbers relate to heatmap-weight, heatmap-intensity, heatmap-radius and heatmap-opacity?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These numbers are used to define so-called [interpolate expressions](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#interpolate). In the first case, it's a [data expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#data-expressions) because it's based on `mag` data value (magnitude of an earthquake), for all the rest, it's based on `zoom` factor (and hence is a [camera expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#camera-expressions)).

Each of these can be treated as pair of numbers: first one in each pair is `stop_input`, second is corresponding output. For example, this...

```
'heatmap-opacity': [
  'interpolate',
  ['linear'],
  ['zoom'],
  7, 1,
  9, 0
]
```

... can be read like this: if `zoom` is 7 or less, use 1 as heatmap-opacity, if `zoom` is 9 or greater, use 0, and interpolate linearly in between.